# error: assignment to expression with array type in c

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, linked-list

I am using this function to create a linked list where each node is a card from a complete deck, however I am getting this weird mistake. Any help?

```
typedef struct cards
{
  char card[3];
  struct cards * next;
} cards_t;

cards_t * make_list(char ** deck) //function to make list
{
   int j = 0;
   cards_t *head = malloc (sizeof(cards_t));

   for (cards_t * iterator = head; j<52; iterator = iterator->next, j++)
   {
      iterator->card = deck[j];
      iterator->next = malloc(sizeof(cards_t));
   }

   return head;
}
```

Comment: `card` is an array, and cannot be used as LHS of `=` operator.

Comment: how do I fix it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to copy the string char by char or use copy function from string.h.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cards
{
  char card[3];
  struct cards * next;
} cards_t;

cards_t * make_list(char ** deck) //function to make list
{
   int j = 0;
   cards_t *head = malloc (sizeof(cards_t));

   for (cards_t * iterator = head; j<52; iterator = iterator->next, j++)
   {
      strcpy(iterator->card,deck[j]);
      iterator->next = malloc(sizeof(cards_t));
   }

   return head;
}
```